# Specflow feature code behind file is not generated properly

Tags: specflow

When I create a new feature file, then I am getting the below error in the code behind file

```
Could not find CodeBehindGenerator binary at location 
C:\USERS\XXXX\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\15.0_A8FC0FAD\EXTENSIONS\0XCK4AN4.WWW\TechTalk.SpecFlow.VisualStudio.CodeBehindGenerator.exe.

Please open an issue at https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/
```

I have used the below packages

```
<package id="SpecFlow" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="SpecFlow.CustomPlugin" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="SpecFlow.MsTest" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
```

**Note:** It was working til yesterday and suddenly the above mentioned error is throwing in the code behind file.

I have tried by upgrading the latest specflow version (3.0.188). But, still the above issue exist.

Comment: I was able to get around this by using an older version from https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.VisualStudio/releases/tag/v2017.2.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was an error in the VS Extension we updated yesterday.

See: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/1456

New version will be published in the next hours.

---

The next time, please open an issue on GitHub and no Stack Overflow question. Thanks!

Comment: You can only create issues on the main SpecFlow repository.

Comment: I realised that when I compared the link above to where I was and removed my comment subsequently. Thanks for getting on this so quick!